# WPF Markup Not Seeing Type in a Different Namespace

Tags: wpf, data-binding, namespaces

I'm sure this is a very noob question for those with WPF databinding experience, but I am a noob. So apologies ahead of time:

I'm trying to bind a collection of objects (IEnumerable) to a listbox as shown below.  The problem is that when my LogEntry type is in the same namespace (ActivityLog) as my "codebehind", I can see the object's properties rendered in the listbox.
However; when the LogEntry type is in a different namespace (ActivityLog.Classes) nothing shows in the listbox.

I've tried adding the ActivityLog.Classes namespace in the xaml markup (xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ActivityLog.Classes"), but I'm sure there's some additional step I'm missing.

Please help.

```
namespace ActivityLog
{
    public partial class LogPage : Window
    {
        public LogPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<LogEntry> leList = new List<LogEntry>() {  new LogEntry() { StartDate=DateTime.Parse("2011-05-10 9:58:00"), ActivityDescription="Three" + Environment.NewLine},  
                                                            new LogEntry() { StartDate=DateTime.Parse("2011-05-10 9:58:00"), ActivityDescription="Four" + Environment.NewLine}};
            this.lstBox.ItemsSource = leList;
        }
    }

    public class LogEntry
    {
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public string ActivityDescription { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="ActivityLog.LogPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ActivityLog.Classes"  
        Title="LogPage" Height="564" Width="414" >
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Width="361" Margin="20,50,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="lstBox" Height="429" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StartDate}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ActivityDescription}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Read the **[formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)** before abusing the code please.

Comment: Sorry.Been trying to format it.

Comment: Well, stop it please unless you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the ItemSource of the ListBox twice. Once in your codebehind

```
this.lstBox.ItemsSource = leList;
```

then again in your xaml

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

In the example provided only the codebehind version is correct and you should remove the xaml version.

Your xaml version is actually binding to the DataContext property of your LogPage, so if you want to hook it up that way your codebehind should be setting

```
this.DataContext = leList;
```

Comment: Confirmed that the ItemSource="{Binding}" is redundant.  However, if the LogEntry class is in a different namespace (than the codebehind class), then the listbox still does not render any items.

Comment: That is not my experience, so you have something else going on. So removing the xaml didn't fix it?

Comment: No. Did yours work even by encasing the LogEntry class in a different namespace?  In the original example it's in the same space as the codebehind class (ie: ActivityLog), so it should work as is.  But putting LogEntry into a separate/different namespace (eg: ActivityLog.Classes) is where it breaks it for me, and doesnt' show anything in the listbox.

Comment: Yes it works here, I took a copy of your code into a new project, worked as is. Moved the LogEntry into a new namespace and it continued to work.

Answer (score 0):

The lines binding the textbox should say:

```
Text="{Binding Path=(local:StartDate)}"
Text="{Binding Path=(local:ActivityDescription)}"
```